# JQuery prevent form from being submitted inside ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to JQuery and ajax in general and I want to disable form submit after I get data from my controller back (I am using Asp.net core MVC). Thing is that even tho I cancel submit it submits anyways as shown bellow:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
                var link = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';
                var args = {
                    arg1: Elem1.val(),
                    arg2: Elem2.val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: link,
                    data: args,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.canacess); //Shows False
                        if (data.canacess== true) {
                            AllEnable();
                        }
                        else { //Goes here
                            e.preventDefault(); //Dont do this
                            alert(data.erromessage); //Do this
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error. Kontaktujte správce.");
                        return;
                    }
                });
            });
```

I think it has to do something with ajax because anywhere else in code it works.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` needs to be invoked within the scope of the `submit` function handler. Right now you're invoking it in the AJAX callback handler which is far too late to have any effect.

Comment: Ok, so is there any way that I can stop form from being submitted until I decide whether I submit it or not?

Comment: Sure. I added an answer for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop form submit during ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528234/how-to-stop-form-submit-during-ajax-call) Ignore the accepted answer and look at the others like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7528365/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` needs to be invoked within the scope of the `submit` function handler. Right now you're invoking it in the AJAX callback handler which is far too late to have any effect.

> Is there any way that I can stop form from being submitted until I decide whether I submit it or not?

Yes. To do that you need to *always* call `e.preventDefault()` in order to stop the form submission so that you give the AJAX request time to execute and return a response. Then, based on that response, you can directly submit the HTMLFormElement object, note *not* the jQuery object, and send the form data to the specified `action`. Try this:

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = this;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
    data: {
      arg1: Elem1.val(),
      arg2: Elem2.val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.canacess) {
        AllEnable();
        form.submit();
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error. Kontaktujte správce.");
    }
  });
});
```

Also note that when using boolean values in conditions it's redundant to compare them to true/false. Similarly, the `return` in the `error` handler is redundant as it's the last statement in the function anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answear! Form now submits but need to pass some parameters to my controller like model and all.. Is there way to do it? Btw: I am aproving your answear because it does what I asked for.